# Test class covers only 50% of trigger

Tags: unit-test

```
@istest
public class beforeinserfieldnewobj_TC
{
static testmethod void beforeinserfieldnewobj()
{
account a=new account(description='xxxx');
insert a;
contact con=new contact();
con.lastname=a.name;
con.accountid=a.id;
insert con;
}
}
```

It is showing the error like this..........!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The image you are showing is of the code that is not being covered. What you want to do is take a look at the errors on the test itself. Notice on the Tests tab it shows red x's next to each execution of your test. You want to click on the plus sign then the plus sign next to the test class that failed. Double click on the failed method to see the Errors.
I would also recommend changing up your trigger to check your trigger context variables outside of the for loop.

Comment: Thanx bro but i am new could u please do it...........! and send i can see and realize and i can learn from u..........!

Comment: @AzuSfdc did you look at the error? I can definitely help you understand the error but no I can't write it for you. The great thing about salesforce is all of the wonderful resources out there. Trailhead, workbooks, cookbooks and forums like this one.

Comment: could u please send the links that means documents about test classes i dont know where are there in salesforce could u.......?

Comment: This session was good http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=n9amswhOxJw and here is a hello world type example from salesforce https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_qs_test.htm